# hiding a DIV when resolution is smaller than

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all, I'm a n00b when it comes to coding and also PHP but I like to design and I like to write.
Question is hopefully simple and I've tried to search for an answer and also tried out a few answers I thought was spot on, but I can't seem to get it to work. Either nothing happens at all to differ low from high resolutions or I make another error and get a blank screen instead :/

My DIV is:

```
<div id="logo_float"><a href="/" title="xyz"><img width="192" height="192" src="../img/logo_float.png"></a></div>
```

My CSS for the div is:

```
#logo_float
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px !important;
    left: 80px !important;
}
```

I found this part somewhere (and it looked pretty straight forward) but I can't seem to get it to work..

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    // code for small viewports
} else {
    // code for large viewports
}
```

I want my DIV (the floating logo) to show on big resolution screens but it kinda messes things up when using a phone, smaller tablet or a really low resolution in general, and I just want to skip it on low res.

If someone here could help me put this shit together I would be forever grateful :)

Comment: use css media queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a css based on screen-width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #logo_float {
      display:none
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that quick fix.
Adding a min and/or max width like this helped me a lot!
And thanks to everyone else wo also answered my question.
Problem solved :)

Comment: awesome, help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    #logo_float{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

It will allows you that your element will be displayed on screens higher than 1024px and to be hidden on screens with less than 1024px.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for CSS media queries here.

Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Specifically:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .your-class {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This will hide anything with the class `.your-class` on screens that are smaller in width than 1000px.

I like to use a `.no-mobile` class when doing this like so:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .no-mobile{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also pro Media Query. But if you need javascript/jQuery to do this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){      
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $('#logo_float').hide();
    } else {
        $('#logo_float').show();
    }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $('#logo_float').hide();
    } else {
        $('#logo_float').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. javascript/jQuery worked great, but as did the media query so I'll stick to that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CSS media queries for this. You can hide div for specific resolutions.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    div#logo_float {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

this will hide div with **id=logo_float** in resolution higher or equal to 320 and lower then 768.

Reference link : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp